# Retrieve data from new Firebase

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase

Please help. After migrating to new Firebase I can't retrieve data.
Use this construction:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        print("\(postDict)")
    })
}
```

After running I see error:

```
2016-05-19 10:04:22.264 123a[88652:13688922] The default app has not been configured yet.
2016-05-19 10:04:22.276 123a[88652:13688922] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MissingDatabaseURL', reason: 'Failed to get FIRDatabase instance: FIRApp object has no databaseURL in its FirebaseOptions object.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I read documentation, but can't resolve this problem.
GoogleService-Info.plist I add to project.

Comment: Did you use FIRApp.configure() before ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes, of course

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I didn't see this answer yet, I had to add the configure call to the AppDelegate init method. So it looks like:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    // Firebase Init
    FIRApp.configure()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The google documentation only cover for pod build which I'm not preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem.
I looked for linking problems that are related to the plist but that wasn't the problem.
I thought maybe it has caused because of that my initial view controller is revoked before the configurations are completed.
I solved the problem by experimenting a bit.

My initial view controller was this:

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

I've changed that to this:

```
    var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

Crash resolved.

Comment: This method resolve crash, but I don't take data from firebase

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me. I tried every single one of them. and keep getting the same error.

Comment: Same issues here Chris. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: I have the same issue, I have tried everything, does anyone have anything else to add?

Answer (score 3):

So, with mine, I also had a ref being declared immediately when the view controller was instantiated. I had to make it load after the app had been configured in the app delegate with `FIRApp.configure()`.

Before:

```
let serverRef = Firebase("firebaseURL")
```

After:

```
lazy var serverRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

This delays the instantiation of the database reference until its needed, which wont be until `viewDidLoad` on your initial view controller.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer given by @ColdLogic, the reason I had this error was because I had my Firebase database reference being created in an init method on a view controller, **not** in the viewDidLoad method. Since the init methods for all classes that are instantiated when the app launches are called **before** the application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate, it was causing this crash. Moving this line of code:

```
class MyViewController {

   var firebaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      ...
      firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      ...
   }
}
```

to here:

```
class MyViewController {

   var firebaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      ...
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      ...
      self.firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   }
}
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I too had a problem with the Firebase Database. Fixed it by adding

```
import FirebaseDatabase
```

to my code

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today, you need the "firebase_url": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com" at google-services.json and for that do this steps https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#android
If you had one file from google cloud platform before, maybe there are some differences and you have to check. For me this works.

Comment: It would be better to include the relevant parts from the link(s) into the answer. Links may disappear.

Comment: i set key "firebase_url" in google plist file but this don't help me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to change the configure to be called before calling the super applicationDidLaunch:

```
[FIRApp configure];

[super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: I using Swift. and in my project set FIRApp.configure() after application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions method in AppDelegate. But this don't help me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error until I made `FIRApp.configure()` the first line in the `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have downloaded the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from your Firebase console and added to the root of your project directory.

Once you have added it call this function from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate:

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

Thats it, it should be up and running!

Comment: @jankigadhiya I can't seem to find a new question here, the answer looks fine

Comment: @jankigadhiya this shouldn't be down voted. Thanks egor.zhdan for your response here.

Comment: @JunaidMukhtar I have not downvoted & sorry for the comment