# The default app has not been configured yet

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to upgrade my app to the new version of Firebase. I went through the setup guide and edited all of my code to match the new syntax. However, when I run the app, I get these two errors.

```
The default app has not been configured yet.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MissingDatabaseURL', reason: 'Failed to get FIRDatabase instance: FIRApp object has no databaseURL in its FirebaseOptions object.'
```

I have  `FIRApp.configure()` in the AppDelegate and I have the GoogleServices-Info.plist imported into my project. The plist has all of the correct info as well. Anyone else running into this or know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at some of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316179/retrieve-data-from-new-firebase) answers?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here's the answer to your problem:

To configure Firebase you have to execute *FIRApp.configure()* somewhere. After this is done you can use *let firebaseDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()* to get a reference to that database and start using it. The problem isn't with Firebase "per se" but with how Swift behaves.

If you put `FIRApp.configure()` in your AppDelegate `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` and then in the `MyDatabase class` you use `let firebaseDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` *outside* of your declared functions *sometimes* the code `FIRDatabase.database().reference()` executes before the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function is executed.

Essentially your class is trying to get a reference to the Firebase database *before* it has a chance to configure itself, generating the error in the console "The default app has not been configured yet."

*Note: This doesn't happen all the time, sometimes the application is slow to start, in iOS Simulator for example, and it doesn't have a chance to finish before MyDatabase "let" executes and tries to get a reference.*

That is why moving the FIRApp.configure() code to override init() in AppDelegate works, essentially it makes sure the configure code gets executed when AppDelegate is initialised (in this and most cases, before MyDatabase is initialised)

```
override init() {
   super.init()
   FIRApp.configure()
   // not really needed unless you really need it FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}
```

Also make sure you super.init() (so you super classes get the "message") so you override doesn't do more harm than good.

Comment: I solved it by moving my `ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` inside `viewDidLoad` method of my UIViewController, and declared `var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!`. Are there any downsides to this, or is there a reason to prefer overriding the `init()` of `AppDelegate`?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to move it to the init() function, just make sure that you don't have any other globally accessible structs/classes, etc accessing the Firebase objects before its configured.

Comment: your explanation makes me clear, thanks its works perfect for me.

Comment: I have globals accessing Firebase objects ie `let db = Firestore.firestore()` because I can guarantee that it is not nil. If I wait until onViewDidLoad to set it equal then I've got to turn them into optionals, which I like to avoid when I can.

Comment: @VladV I try to avoid forced optionals where I can. I can't decide which is less complicated.

Comment: @ScriptKitty Optionals are really there so you don't have to check for nil all the time. If something is nil you have bigger problems anyway, since it means your concurrent code doesn't wait for callbacks that guarantee that something is there before using it and optionals hide that from you even more.

Comment: I don't know why, but doing this disables app delegate swizzling. So if you are using Phone Authentication that relies on app delegate swizzling, then you might not want to put the configure function in init.

Comment: @WYS swizzling applies to methods not objects, so probably your swizzling swizzles the init method in app AppDelegate among others? Also it might be the case that a hard coded init in the code you write might take precedence over the swizzling code you also write somewhere else in Xcode. So when compiling, it just happens that, that declaration is superseded by this one.

Comment: how does this look for `FIRApp configure` in objective c? I write JS not native code..

Comment: @RedBaron [FIRApp configure];       FIRApp is a class and configure is one of its class method.

Answer (score 44):

I'm also using `Fabric` and in my case it was the order of `Fabric` and `Firebase` initializations. I had to initialize `Firebase` first.

So changing

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    ...
}
```

to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    ...
}
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In `AppDelegate.m`, outside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,

```
override init() {
   FIRApp.configure()
   FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Did you have the persistenceEnabled call there the whole time? That being called first will have triggered the FIRDatabase class to to check whether it was configured, and fail. You can move the configure back to where it was, as long as you move the persistenceEnabled flag with it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are having `DATABASE_URL` key in your `GoogleService-Info.plist`

Comment: This was the problem for me.  Downloaded it again and this key-value pair was present.

Now a new problem occurred, and it seems the SDK doesn't know what to do with database locations outside of the US.  I used Belgium, and the SDK couldn't parse the URL.  I used USA and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 - Easy Solution

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

return true
}


//MARK:- This function will auto run and firebase will configure successfully
override init() {
    super.init()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        // not really needed unless you really need it 
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

iOS 9.2
Swift 2.1.1
Xcode 7.2.1
Mac OSX 10.10.5

Same error here using the following code:

**AppDelegate.swift**:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FIRApp.configure()


        return true
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Create some data in Firebase db:
        db.child("key").child("subkey").setValue("hello world")

    }
```

I also added the file `GoogleService-Info.plist` to my project directory as described in the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites).

And I made my Firebase db public with the following [Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#configuring_rules):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Making the following changes to ViewController.swift is what worked for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var db: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        db.child("key").child("subkey").setValue("hello world")

    }
```

Prior to running my app, my Firebase db looked like this:

```
myiosdata-abc123: null
```

After running my app, my Firebase db looked like this:

```
myiosdata-abc123
- key
   |
   +--- subkey: “hello world”
```

Answer (score 1):

I had several normal working projects with `FIRApp.configure ()` code in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

Everything worked great for quite some time, but yesterday and today I opened a `Swift 3` project inside my `Xcode 7.3.1` (I am still working in `Swift 2`, but opened `Swift 3` project to see what is changed), and suddenly in all my `Swift 2` apps and projects that I am still working on, got the same error:

> The default app has not been configured yet

Every project now when I open in XCode, getting same error, I didn't know what to do, but after implementing @MichaelWilliams' code, everything works fine again.

I have debug my Xcode (clear and reload console), but nothing works beside this new approach by Michael.

**This one resolved my problem:**

```
override init() {
   FIRApp.configure()
   FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}
```

Can this new code somehow make my app's unstable and can I be afraid to see problems with connecting/working with Firebase database now?

Answer (score 1):

Try re-download GoogleService-Info.plist from your console and add it to your project, That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 9, Swift 4 and Firebase 4 please do the following:

```
override init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: A good answer would include the file name (`AppDelegate` here) where we need to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution to me here is to have **lazy properties** in case you want to have the db on top of your file. So let's say you have a FirebaseService class where you want to have `Firestore.firestore()` db constant to use it in all of the functions in that class:

```
private lazy var db = Firestore.firestore()
```

Or if you are using Firebase Storage:

```
private lazy var storage = Storage.storage().reference()
```

Also keep in mind that if you are referencing the Database/Storage in `init()` of your classes, you still might have the same problem so avoid that.