# Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I am new to coding so I am sorry if the answer to this is obvious.

I've tried to sync my app to the Firebase server, I've installed cocoapods, added the GoogleService info plist. However, when I try to create a new user, I get the error:

> The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization

App Delegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> ObjCBool {

       FIRApp.configure()

        return true
    }
```

Code I am using to signup users

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class signUpViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet var fullNameTextField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var contactNumberTextField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var dateOfBirth: UIDatePicker?


    func  createMyAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alarm = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alarm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: { (ACTION) -> Void
            in self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        self.present(alarm, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func continueButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if fullNameTextField?.text == "" || contactNumberTextField?.text == "" || emailTextField?.text == "" || passwordTextField?.text == "" {

            createMyAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please complete all fieds")

        } else {

        // This will create a new user
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: (self.emailTextField?.text!)!, password: (self.passwordTextField?.text!)!) { (user, error) in


        // this code will check the user isnt nil

                if let u = user {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createProfile", sender: self)

                }
                else
                {

                    self.createMyAlert(title: "Oops", message: "Error" )

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've tried to format your code with no success, please take some time to make your code as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like call to **FIRApp.configure()** is not getting executed before you actually trying to access the database. Instead of configuring in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> ObjCBool {
```

Try to override init method and cconfigure fireapp in tha as below :

```
override init() {
super.init()
FIRApp.configure()
 // not really needed unless you really need it        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
 }
```

Check below link for more detail:

[The default app has not been configured yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334323/the-default-app-has-not-been-configured-yet)