# iOS - Firebase Storage trying to initialize before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

My app worked fine and then suddenly the next day before I made any changes, it started throwing an error "no default storage bucket found".

This error occurs even before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions has had a chance to run.  I cannot figure out why the storage module would even try to initialize itself at this point. I don't have any references to the storage until much later. I'm using Xcode 9.4.1, and the latest Firebase modules (Firebase 5.6.0) and storage (3.0.0).

Any thoughts on this odd behavior and possible fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code? or create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There could be a few factors causing this behaviour. Most likely (since your saying its changes all of a sudden) a dependency change.

Having said that - I have seen this very issue in the past when I was calling calling the firebase storage before initialising (and like you at first thought it was failing to initialise).

This thread helped me:

[iOS Swift Firebase Storage error "No default Storage bucket found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485769/ios-swift-firebase-storage-error-no-default-storage-bucket-found)