# Error with Firebase 4.0 - 'The default Firebase app has not yet been configured' though FirebaseApp.configure() seems correct

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

i just updated Firebase from 3.0 to 4.0, i'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.3.

I have the required firebase application initialiser, as below:

```
func application(_ application:Application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
        FirebaseApp.configure()

    }
```

However, I still get:

```
2017-08-07 19:33:56.855 hollerApp[33802] <Error> [Firebase/Core][ICOR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: GOOGLE_URL libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException(lldb)'
```

i've tried everything listed on stack overflow and any new ideas on how to fix this and load my app would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already seen this, but I thought I should show you instead until I can get home and look how mine is setup: [The default app has not been configured yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334323/the-default-app-has-not-been-configured-yet)

That might be the correct place to add it, but you may be referencing the database (or Firebase) somewhere else before it has been configured.

Comment: Please don't post answers which just link to another Stack Overflow post.  With sufficient reputation, you will be able to comment on any post, and flag questions as duplicates.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was the issue. That was killing me.

Comment: @Jal I don't have enough reputation to comment and he was getting a different error then the post I linked. Just wanted him to fix his problem.

Comment: which you did most effectively